# (One button creates one element) multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to have a setup where there are multiple buttons that each add one element (and one only) to a list (further down my webpage) + disables the button which was just clicked (but not the other buttons). Moreover, if you click on the corresponding element that was created, it deletes itself and enables the corresponding button back.

I managed to do it for one instance of a button, with the following code :

Javascript :

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1')
  , sortie = document.getElementById('sortie');

function createSortie() {
    var d = document.createElement("span");
    d.id = "sortieBtn1";
    d.className = "label label-success";
    d.onclick = removeSelf;
    d.innerHTML = "Hey, sup', now click on me to make me disappear";
    sortie.appendChild(d);
}

function removeSelf() {
    document.getElementById('sortieBtn1').remove();
    document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = false;

}

function modifyButton(a) {
    document.getElementById(a).disabled = true;
}
```

HTML :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" onclick="createSortie();modifyButton(this.id)">Click on me to create a new element</button><br />
<br/>
<br/>
Sortie :
<div id="sortie"></div>
```

Example : http://www.codeply.com/go/SEL7ZqBI49

I now want it for multiple buttons, I could of course do something [like this](http://www.codeply.com/go/AIIGEH2OYU), but there are smarter ways to do achieve what I need (*), namely, more buttons and obviously, without having designated functions for each pair of button/created element.

(*) : maybe - but not mandatory - with something similar to [function factories](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures) in R ?

Any idea on how to achieve that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually pass the reference to the clicked button as a parameter to the `onclick` function which makes things lots easier than trying to work with `id`s. Also, you won't have to find the elements every time and thus you can apply to as many items as you want. Check a working example:

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('.btn'),
  sortie = document.getElementById('sortie');

// Creates the labels on the output div when a button is clicked
function createSortie(button) {
  // Create a label using a <span> element
  var label = document.createElement("span");

  // The ID will not be used but it's useful to link it to the 
  // originating button in some way
  label.id = "sortie" + button.id;

  label.className = "label label-success";

  // Set click handler on the label
  label.onclick = function() {
    // Remove itself, using self-reference as argument
    removeLabel(label);

    // Toggle the originating button to enabled again
    // (disabled = false)
    toggleButton(button, false);
  };

  label.innerHTML = "I''m label for " + button.id;

  // Set button to disabled
  toggleButton(button, true);

  // Add this label to sortie
  sortie.appendChild(label);
}

// Removes a label, passed as parameter
function removeLabel(label) {
  label.remove();
}

// Toggles a button ON or OFF, as specified on the state parameter
function toggleButton(button, state) {
  button.disabled = state;
}
```

```css
.label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h3>Buttons</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" onclick="createSortie(this);">Element 1</button>
<br />
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" onclick="createSortie(this);">Element 2</button>

<h3>Sortie :</h3>

<div id="sortie">
</div>
```

I also forked your Codeply: http://www.codeply.com/go/cJwYL0iBeY

Feel free to ask anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you use classes for the buttons, and then use a number in the ID's, it would be easy to target the sortie belonging to each button, something like

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
 buttons[i].addEventListener('click', btnClick);
}

function  btnClick() {
 var sortie = document.getElementById('sortie' + this.id.replace('btn',''));
 createSortie(sortie, this);
}

function createSortie(sortie, button) {
    var d = document.createElement("span");
    d.className = "label label-success";
    d.addEventListener('click', function() {
     button.disabled = false;
        this.remove();
    });
    d.innerHTML = "Hey, sup', now click on me to make me disappear";
    sortie.appendChild(d);
    button.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1">Click on me to create a new element</button><br />
<br/><br/>
Sortie :
<div id="sortie1"></div>
<br/><br/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2">Click on me to create a new element</button><br />
<br/><br/>
Sortie :
<div id="sortie2"></div>
<br/><br/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn3">Click on me to create a new element</button><br />
<br/><br/>
Sortie :
<div id="sortie3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle for you, it is mostly based on relative selection and not on IDs, i pass the whole element in function and then do further action on that basis, have a look

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Le5vbg5/)

HTML

```
<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" onclick="createSortie(this);modifyButton(this)">Click on me to create a new element</button><br />
<br/>
<br/>
Sortie :
<div class="sortie"></div>
</div>

<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" onclick="createSortie(this);modifyButton(this)">Click on me to create a new element</button><br />
<br/>
<br/>
Sortie :
<div class="sortie"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function createSortie(elem) {

  elem.parentElement.querySelector('.sortie').innerHTML+='<span class="label label-success" onclick="removeSelf(this)">Hey, sup, now click on me to make me disappear</span>';
}

function removeSelf(ele) {
console.log( ele.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('button'));

    ele.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('button').removeAttribute('disabled')

ele.remove();
}

function modifyButton(ele) {
   ele.setAttribute('disabled','disabled')
}
```